# What do the numbers in .tmj file stand for

Tags: tiled

[image]

This file is exported form Tiled ，
How can I use this to render the whole scene

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/json-map-format/#layer) says it's an array of [Global Tile IDs](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/global-tile-ids/). Tiled has a really good manual, you should really try reading it first.